# $state.go after a timeout or in $ionicPlatform.ready makes a boolean seem truthy and falsy at the same time

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

We want to have a dynamic startup state in the our application depending on certain factors (scroll down if you're interested in the context).

We have the following code to achieve it: we have a fake `routing` state which is a default state with no UI which makes decisions about routing.

```
mainModule.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   // ...
   $stateProvider.state({
      'routing': {
        url: '/routing',
        controller: 'RoutingController'
      }
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/routing');
});

mainModule.controller('RoutingController', function($state, $ionicPlatform, $timeout) {
    function doNormalStartup() {
        console.log("doNormalStartup");
        $state.go('timeline');
    }

    doNormalStartup(); // fine
    // $ionicPlatform.ready(doNormalStartup); // double ng-hide bug!
    // $timeout(0).then(doNormalStartup); // bug as well
});
```

For simplicity I put in this example that it should always route to `timeline` state. When I do state navigation directly in `RoutingController`, it works fine, but when I do it in `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback, it produces a weird bug:

we have two HTML nodes with `ng-show` bound to the same variable, but one negated. So at all times, exactly one of them should be shown. However, angular adds `ng-hide` to both nodes!

The bug only happens when firing the navigation inside `$ionicPlatform.ready` or after a timeout.

[image]

It seems like angular binding machinery gets broken at some point.
Any ideas how can this possibly happen?

**Context:**

If the Android app was started via a deep link from the web - i.e. HTTP link intercepted by an app, we want to read the original request URL and decide about routing.

To do this, I use [webintent plugin](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent). But I can read its output only when the plugin is initialized, i.e. inside `$ionicPlatform.ready` callback.

**Edit:**

I tried changing the bound expression from `showEmptyTimeline` to `foo.showEmptyTimeline` and later `showEmptyTimeline()` method call, inside the call I `console.log` the contents and they're a boolean `false`.

Changing the callback from `doNormalStartup` to `function(){doNormalStartup()}` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try to console.log() the showEmptyTimeline the moment you need it. What is the value? Maybe it's undefined!

Comment: I think this could be linked to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13380 I need to investigate a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems seems to be [this angular bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13380) in angular 1.4.x. Using `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   doNormalStartup();
}
```

instead of your code